# How do I use a promiscuous socket in Python whilst capturing TCP packets?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ip

So I've managed to get this working with IP headers, this code can collect IP packets and read IP headers. However, I want to be able to collect TCP packets and read TCP headers.

```py
def main():
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    conn.bind((HOST, 0))
    conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

I tried to implement this using SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_RAW, as follows, but I get these errors:

```py
def main():
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    conn.bind((HOST, 0))
    conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

`conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON) OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`

When commenting this line out, I get this error:

`raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535) OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied`

Comment: TCP packets are IP packets too. You have to use raw sockets but then parse the IP and TCP headers yourself.

Comment: I understand that they are the same thing, I think I may have phrased my question wrong. How would I go about parsing a TCP header from an IP packet?

Comment: Not sure what you problem is. Do you understand how these protocols are stacked in the packet. i.e. where to find the IP header, when and where to find the TCP header, what the various parts of the header mean etc?

Comment: I have an understanding of the TCP/IP stack, and I assume that's what I'm dealing with here. However I don't think I know exactly when and where to find the TCP header and the IP header. I'm confused as to where I could find both the IP and the TCP header within one bit of captured data. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: With IP_HDRINCL you are basically getting the packet, starting with the IP header. First comes the IP header, then the TCP header, then the TCP payload. Exactly like on the wire. Size and content are defined in the standard but there is also a good summary at [wikipedia: IPv4#Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and [wikipedia:TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)

Comment: Oh I see, I think that I've completely overlooked encapsulation. I just found [this](https://www.omnisecu.com/tcpip/tcpip-encapsulation-decapsulation.php) article and diagram. From how I interpret this diagram, the TCP/Transport Layer's Header is encapsulated as part of the Data section of the IP/Network Layer. Would this be correct?

Comment: Correct. Basically TCP is the payload for IP.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: @bailey_f just make sure you actually pay attention to what the IP header tells you. Doing promiscuous monitoring, you are going to receive all kinds of IP packets, not just TCP.  It maybe UDP, ICMP, etc instead. The IP header will tell you if the IP data payload is actually TCP data or not.

Comment: You raise a good point, I am, at the moment, checking packet protocol and filtering based on that. Thank you!